# Add a "Right-click on a .WAV file, Convert to MP3" extension to Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, batch, context-menu, shell-extensions

I created a key in the Windows registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Convert to MP3\command
```

with:

```
"D:\tools\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%1" -acodec libmp3lame -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 256k "%1.mp3"
```

It works, except that the filename is not exactly what I want:

Input: `test.wav`, Output: `test.wav.mp3`

whereas I'd like the output filename to be `test.mp3`.

I also tried with:

```
"D:\tools\ffmpeg.exe" ... "%~n1.mp3"
```

[like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215539/1422096), but it doesn't work: the output is `%~n1.mp3` then!

**How to remove the original extension like this, and replace by .mp3?**

PS: I'm looking for a solution without involving a .bat file, but only the registry. If not possible, it's ok to use a bat file.

Comment: Use a .cmd file and do it from there. It should work then.

Comment: @LPChip Isn't there a way to do it just from a single line in registry? Are `%~n1` things supported *only* in cmd/bat file?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumed that ffmpeg.exe is included by path variable, use

```
cmd /q /c for %%I in ("%1") do ffmpeg -i %%I -acodec libmp3lame -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 256k "%%~nI.mp3"
```

as one-liner without bat file.

Comment: Posted on your request. As a >2k user I should focus on more advanced commands & give chance for newcomers to answer, hence I initially posted in comment. If you'd award this bounty to me, I'll refund it to you by sponsoring your next question of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a .BAT file (don't know if it's possible without a BAT file). The key is to use `%~n1.mp3`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215539/1422096).

File `____LameMP3me.bat`:

```
"D:\Documents\software\____PORTABLE\____useful-tools\ffmpeg.exe" -i %1 -acodec libmp3lame -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 256k "%~n1.mp3"
```

In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Lame MP3 me!\command`:

```
"D:\Documents\software\____PORTABLE\____useful-tools\____LameMP3me.bat" "%1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of registry hacking you could just put the `.bat` file (or a `.lnk` file pointing to it) into `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`.

Here's a cygwin + bash solution for the file extension problem, requires exactly one additional line of code thanks to https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

You would start it by `c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe <scriptname> <filename>`

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME="${1%.*}"

"/cygdrive/d/tools/ffmpeg.exe" -i "\"$1\"" -acodec libmp3lame -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 256k "\"${FILE_NAME}.mp3\""

#keep the console window open, uncomment if not necessary
read
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but using `SendTo` vs. contextual menu command doesn't change anything to the original problem (i.e. having the files named `test.wav.mp3` instead of `test.mp3`). Also using SendTo is longer to do when doing it a lot (right click, click on SendTo, find the right item) than a direct Context menu item.

Comment: I know, but keep in mind that people may come to this place via searching google. I certainly wish I had known about this little trick much sooner.

Comment: Regarding your filename problem. I never learned power shell, so what I do is install cygwin and run more involved stuff as a bash script. But that's hardly a solution for you I guess.

Comment: @Basj added the bash solution just in case